# How to get around in coastal southern Chile now that the Navimag ferry is suspended?

Tags: ferries, chile

In southern Chile, many communities are only accessible by sea.  For example,
according to the [Wikipedia article on Villa Puerto Edén](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_Puerto_Ed%C3%A9n):

> Owing to the large tidewater glaciers caused by the region’s super-high precipitation, it is only accessible by sea, on the Navimag ferry from Puerto Montt in the north, or Puerto Natales in the south.

However, the [Navimag website has a *comunicado oficial*](http://www.navimag.com/site/comunicado-oficial/):

> Me corresponde informarles que Navimag Ferries ha decidido redestinar el Ferry Evangelistas a un servicio de carga a contar del próximo mes de Septiembre. Por tal razón, se suspende el servicio de transporte de pasajeros en esta nave en la Ruta Fiordos (Puerto Natales – Puerto Montt ; – Puerto Montt – Puerto Natales).

Which basically means that the ferry is suspended.  The aforementioned Wikipedia article does state that *There is also a monthly boat from Caleta Tortel*, but the source is offline (print book) I can't find details about this.  The [Spanish language article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Ed%C3%A9n) has no information about transportation.  In conflict with Wikipedia, the Soviet Genshtab map (via [topomapper.net](http://www.topomapper.com/splitscreen.html?zoom=8&lat=-49.333333&lon=-74.666667&layers=00000000B0)) does show an airfield:

[image: screenshot Genshtab map]

<sup>Screenshot from Genshtab-map around Villa Puerto Edén</sup>.

How can one get around in coastal southern Chile now that the Navimag Ferries are suspended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are other ferry companies operating in the area. A thorough search of Google should find these. Also, consider investing in a quality guide book like the ones from Rough Guides.

When we travelled the length of Chile in 2003, we decided to ferry from Puerto Montt to Chaiten and then we went with buses down the Carretera Austral to Coyhaique and from there a short flight with Lan Chile to Punta Arenas. It's an easy drive or bus from there to Puerto Natales. Chaiten may no longer really be active following a major eruption a few years back.

Alternatively, you can do a series of little ferry hops and get down the Carretera Austral like that (see Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carretera_Austral).

Getting to Puerto Eden may be harder now but if you have a month or two, it may be possible. Things take time down there. Sometimes you wait for a bus for a few days just because there wasn't enough people needing it. If you can rent a car and drive it one way, do it. make sure it's a good sturdy car and you are comfortable on lonely gravel roads.

It's a lovely area to visit. But then, the whole country is superb.

Comment: One of the alternative companies: http://www.navieraustral.cl/

Travelling on those small barge ferries over a long distance can leave you feeling a bit poorly.